# TexStudio not loading subfiles from a folder

Tags: texstudio, document-classes

I am using a template, found here: https://github.com/mas-group/project-report . When I open, compile, and view report.tex in TexStudio, the pdf only displays till the abstract page. From my understanding, it should display all of the subfiles, including the acknowledgements, introduction, ch01, ch02, etc. However, it only displays abstract.tex, not the other .tex files within the chapters folder. I think it might be the mas_report.cls file not being a .cwl file, but I don't know how to convert it. Does anyone know what the exact issue is and how to fix it? I also have the same issue when I load the template into OverLeaf.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Check the log for `! LaTeX Error: File ... not found.` You may need to add [a representative sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your `tex` file and give more details on where those files are, perhaps a project structure, and then others can give the best answer.

Comment: There are no "File not found errors". 4 errors do appear when compiling, but the PDF still becomes visible in the view panel: abstract.tex gives a "Can be used only in preamble. \begin{document}" error, and report.tex has a "Unused global option(s): [twosides]." error, a "Option `colorlinks' has already been used,(hyperref) setting the option has no effect" error, and a "Option `pagebackref' has already been used,(hyperref) setting the option has no effect" error. The smallest representative sample I can give is the template in the link, because I am trying to compile the template.

Comment: You should add code and avoid links anyway because links can change and then the question becomes difficult to understand or useless without examples.

Comment: As to the problem, the author of the linked project uses `subfiles`. First of all this package should loaded as last! Second of all, each file which is added by `subfile` should have a document class definition linking to the `subfile` in your case `\documentclass[report.tex]{subfiles}`. If you do add  it to all files, the whole project should start working. You should also inform the author about this problem.

Comment: As to `hyperref`, these are only warnings and might need to be sorted in its own way because options are used multiple times and then ignored. But it is not what cases problems in your question.

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure to upload code in the future instead. Thank you for the help, adding \documentclass[report.tex]{subfiles} to all the related subfiles worked! I also made sure to load the subfile package last. I have contacted the template author about the issue. How can I mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: I'm glad it works. A representative sample does not mean the whole project but the smallest file and minimum extra content, e.g. one linked file, that both reproduce a problem in question. I know it's the extra effort for posters but that will help in future if someone else come here with the same issue and links no longer work.